# Drupal 8 Thunder : how to display only date without time for articles?

Tags: date, drupal-8

I am using Drupal 8 Thunder with the newsplus lite theme and would like to display everywhere only date without time.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure a new date-time format using `/admin/config/regional/date-time`

Put `m/d/Y` as a value for this new format.

Then configure the display of your nodes types and set this format for your date field.